# BackgroundWorker with long-running procedure call using OleDb provider in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I have a long-running oracle procedure (sometimes takes about an hour to finish) which i call from a .net 2.0 windows forms application using OleDb.
I use backgroundWorker to move the job to a separate thread, and in the main thread, i just show some loading gif to prevent application from freezing. But after a while (15 or so minutes), application freezes and unfreezes after the procedure is completed.

What is causing such behavior? BackgroundWorker or OleDb or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Could you get the state of threads? You can use, for example, my tool https://github.com/REASY/ProcInfo4Net/releases. Yes, it's like a PR :)

Comment: I found out the problem. I was using the connection object that was created in my main form(UI thread). When I create another connection object in worker thread, i don't get the UI freeze. But, now i am not sure why didn't UI freeze at the beginning of the procedure call in the first scenario.

Comment: It's really strange... Need more info.

Comment: It doesn't really matter anymore since I resolved it by moving the connection object to the worker thread. Sorry, but I cannot give you the code of the application. Thanks for help anyway, I did try your ProcInfo4Net ;-).